# GSM not responsing?

Tags: arduino, gsm

using gsm 6A module with arduino mega

gsm utx to 3 arduin

gsm rtx to 2 arduino

gsm gnd to gnd arduin

I am not getting any response from gsm and further AT and other command are not displaying.

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

//Create software serial object to communicate with SIM800L
SoftwareSerial mySerial(3, 2); //SIM800L Tx & Rx is connected to Arduino #3 & #2

void setup()
{
  //Begin serial communication with Arduino and Arduino IDE (Serial Monitor)
  Serial.begin(9600);

  //Begin serial communication with Arduino and SIM800L
  mySerial.begin(9600);

  Serial.println("Initializing...");
  delay(1000);

  mySerial.println("AT"); //Once the handshake test is successful, it will back to OK
  updateSerial();
  mySerial.println("AT+CSQ"); //Signal quality test, value range is 0-31 , 31 is the best
  updateSerial();
  mySerial.println("AT+CCID"); //Read SIM information to confirm whether the SIM is plugged
  updateSerial();
  mySerial.println("AT+CREG?"); //Check whether it has registered in the network
  updateSerial();
}

void loop()
{
  updateSerial();
}

void updateSerial()
{
  delay(500);
  while (Serial.available()) 
  {
    mySerial.write(Serial.read());//Forward what Serial received to Software Serial Port
  }
  while(mySerial.available()) 
  {
    Serial.write(mySerial.read());//Forward what Software Serial received to Serial Port
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

good day sir. the rx and tx of gsm module should also be connected to rx and tx ports of arduino mega.